# Consulta MYSQL intervalo de datas e outra data qualquer na mesma consulta

Tags: mysql, query, select

Tenho a seguintes datas como exemplo:

2021-06-01 2021-06-02 2021-06-03 2021-06-04 2021-06-05

gostaria de exibir 2021-06-01, 2021-06-02, 2021-06-03 e 2021-06-05

Estou tentando fazer desta forma: SELECT * FROM funci WHERE data >= '2021-06-01' && data <= '2021-06-03' && data = '2021-06-05' Retorna Vazio.

Se retirado: && data = '2021-06-05' me retorna o intervalo normalmente. O que pode ser feito diferente? Obrigado...

Esclarecer melhor minha duvida:`SELECT data FROM tab.. WHERE data BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-06-03' && data = '2021-06-05'`

Gostaria de Retornar as datas dentro do intervalo e mais uma data fora do intervalo

Comment: `( ( D >= x AND D <= y ) OR D = z )`

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que entendi, você está tentando recuperar datas que estejam entre o intervalo 2021-06-01 e 2021-06-05, e que não sejam iguais a 2021-06-04. Para essa situação o BETWEEN deve funcionar. Tente algo como:

`SELECT * FROM funci WHERE data BETWEEN CONVERT("2021-06-01", DATE) AND CONVERT("2021-06-05", DATE) AND data <> CONVERT("2021-06-04", DATE);`

Comment: Na verdade eu quero retornar todas as datas do intervalo + outra data que não esta dentro do intervalo

Comment: Nesse caso, tente trocar o AND pelo OR:
SELECT * FROM funci WHERE data BETWEEN CONVERT("2021-06-01", DATE) AND CONVERT("2021-06-03", DATE) OR data = CONVERT("2021-06-05", DATE);

Comment: Obrigado... funcionou com seu exemplo